# React: On onBlur event for specific element, capture other element state update by onClick event

Tags: reactjs

There are read-only/ display fields `A` and `C` and input field `B`.
All of the three have specific state values. There is a button to increment the value of field `A`.
Blurring from field `B` should cause summation of fields `A` and `B` into field `C`.

This works fine with the below code except for one expected behavior.
When the focus is in field `B` and then if the user clicks on the `Increment A` button, I need to capture the incremented value of field `A` in the `onBlur()` event handler so that the summation is correct of the fields `A` and `B` in field `C`. Incrementing value of field `A` is conditional such that -  If `A` is currently an odd number then increment it with a delay, else increment it instantly.

The expected behaviour is not happening as `onBlur()` fires before `onClick` and so `onBlur()` do not receive any state updates done by `onClick()`.

Is there any way to achieve the expected behavior?

Code below -

```
const App = () => {
  const [numA, setNumA] = useState(10);
  const [numB, setNumB] = useState(0);
  const [numC, setNumC] = useState(0);

  const incrementA = () => {
    if (numA % 2) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setNumA((a) => a + 1);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      setNumA((a) => a + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>A: {numA}</p>
      <em>
        Note: If 'A' currently is odd then increment it with a delay, else increment it
        instantly
      </em>
      <br />
      <button onClick={incrementA}>Increment A</button>
      <p>
        <em>
          Note: Blurring from 'B' should cause summation of 'A' and 'B' into 'C'
        </em>
        <br />
        B:{" "}
        <input
          value={numB}
          onChange={({ target }) => setNumB(parseInt(target.value))}
          onBlur={() => setNumC(numA + numB)}
        />
      </p>

      <p>C: {numC}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Codesanbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-poitras-z7b7n?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

@abhinandan Khilari

The solution to this above problem can be by using useMemo from React. Let me explain useMemo purpose. It basically listens actively to all of the specified states or props. And once the participating state or prop changes. It runs the inside block. So in your case, the actively participating states are B and A. Against which the C is getting calculated. See the below code and it should work fine.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [numA, setNumA] = useState(10);
  const [numB, setNumB] = useState(0);
  const [numC, setNumC] = useState(0);

  useMemo(() => {
    setNumC(numA + numB)
  },[numA, numB]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>A: {numA}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setNumA((a) => a + 1)}>Increment A</button>
      <p>
        <em>
          Note: Blurring from 'B' should cause summation of 'A' and 'B' into 'C'
        </em>
        <br />
        B:{" "}
        <input
          value={numB}
          onChange={({ target }) => setNumB(parseInt(target.value))}
          onBlur={() => setNumC(numA + numB)}
        />
      </p>

      <p>C: {numC}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul. Actually my bad, I miss some details. I got some conditional async logic for incrementing field `A`. So, I think this approach will not work. I have updated the question.